# Can we skip an input in push down automata

Tags: finite-automata, pushdown-automata

I'm giving a language
$L=\{0^m 1^n 2^m \mid m,n ∈ N\}$. I designed this stack machine in order to accept $L$.
Here, I'm skipping $1$s (no matter how many $1$s there are). Is it acceptable to skip the input this way?[image]

Comment: In [usual definition of PDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#Formal_definition), the thing being pushed in each transition is a **string** of stack alphabet, which is totally fine to be the empty string.

Comment: This question, btw, uses a lot of non-standard symbols. It would be good to define those symbols.

Comment: Its 0 to the power of n, 1 to the power of m and 2 to the power of n.
So is it ok to just skip input 1 as I have done in my machine above?

Comment: I'm implicitly saying in my first comment that it's okay to push empty string into the stack while remaining on the same state to simulate skip. The notation I couldn't guess was the labelling of your transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can skip or ignore an input without pushing it into the stack. In my case (a^i b^j c^k d^j e^i) where i & j >=0 while k >0.
'abcde'is an accepted string so I ll make following PDA so that it will accept my string. In this case I am ignoring C so that I can make a perfect machine.
So, It is possible to skip an input.[image]